# Get frame rate of a video clip in C#

Tags: c#, .net, frame-rate

How to get I get the frame rate of a video clip in C# ? Video clips are in WMV, MP4, MPG formats.

Comment: please show some source code... are you using any library to access the video files ? what have you tried ? what doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IWMPNetwork::frameRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to get frame rate of your video (You need to add `Interop.WMPLib.dll.dll` to your project).

Example code (take from above link):

```
// Add a delegate for the PlayStateChange event.
player.PlayStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(player_PlayStateChange);

// Create an event handler for the PlayStateChange event.
private void player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    // Display the frameRate when the player is playing. 
    switch (e.newState)
    {
        case 3:  // Play State = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying = 3
            if (player.network.frameRate != 0)
            {
                frameRateLabel.Text = "Current Frame Rate: " + player.network.frameRate + " K bits/second";
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31849722/1257607) to do so and helped me a lot.

Actually I invoke the following function, everytime I am printing a new frame:

```
private void FPS_Counter()
{
    _framesRendered++;
    if ((DateTime.Now - _lastTime).TotalSeconds >= 1)
    {
       Log.Debug("FPS: one second has elapsed (fps: " + _fps + ")");
       _fps = _framesRendered;
       _framesRendered = 0;
       _lastTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```