# My FPS Counter is in-accurate any ideas why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame, performancecounter, frame-rate

When I start up my game it stays around 95-101 rapidly changing, in between all of those numbers.. but when I open up the stats bar I'm getting upper 200's low 300's

so wondering why that is still new to c# so be easy on me lol. heres the code
thanks in advance as always ^_^.

```
float deltaTime = 0.0f;

void Update() 
{
    deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    int w = Screen.width, h = Screen.height;

    GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle ();

    Rect rect = new Rect (0, 0, w, h * 2 / 100);
    style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperRight;
    style.fontSize = h * 2 / 100;
    style.normal.textColor = new Color (255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 1.0f);
    float msec = deltaTime * 1000.0f;
    float fps = 1f / deltaTime;
    string text = string.Format ("({1:0.} fps)", msec, fps);
    GUI.Label (rect, text, style);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to display a meaningful FPS rate you need to measure how many frames were rendered *over a constant period of time*, for example **one second**.  Then only after that period do you display the calculated value on screen. This will provide for an *average frames per second* as opposed to an *instantaneous frames per second*, the latter of which is not particularly useful in most cases as it leads to widely fluctuating values.

### Code

First define some fields:

```
DateTime _lastTime; // marks the beginning the measurement began
int _framesRendered; // an increasing count
int _fps; // the FPS calculated from the last measurement
```

Then in your render method you increment the `_framesRendered`.  You also check to see if one second has elapsed since the start of the period:

```
void Update()
{
    _framesRendered++;

    if ((DateTime.Now - _lastTime).TotalSeconds >= 1)
    {
        // one second has elapsed 

        _fps = _framesRendered;                     
        _framesRendered = 0;            
        _lastTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // draw FPS on screen here using current value of _fps          
}
```

### Cross-technology

It should be pointed out that the above code makes no particular use of Unity whilst still being reasonably accurate and is compatible with many frameworks and APIs such as DirectX; OpenGL;  XNA; WPF or even WinForms.

> When I start up my game it stays around 95-101 rapidly changing, in between all of those numbers.. but when I open up the stats bar I'm getting upper 200's low 300's

The ASUS VG248QE is 1ms and the max it can do is 144Hz so it is unlikely you are getting "upper 200's low 300's". FPS is meaningless when VSYNC is turned off on a non-GSYNC monitor. Is your VSYNC turned on?

Comment: Regarding the moment were you should draw the value of _fps it should be inside the condition when one second has elapsed.

Comment: @DanielV not quite, the value of `_fps` needs to be _drawn_ each frame (hence outside of `if` but the determination of `_fps` only gets _updated_ once a second.  It is true that for the first second it will show `0`.  We could if we like not draw anything until the 1st second has ellapsed to make it tidier. :)

Comment: ah! you have a point there, but after the first second the value is more accurate

Comment: I was searching for calculating request per second but didnt like any answers.. then I thought to look for FPS since theres more gamers out there. good stuff +1

Answer (score 2):

In Unity, FPS is equivalent to number of `Updates` that occur in 1 second. This is because `Update()` is called every `Time.deltaTime` seconds.

**InvokeRepeating method**

You can also use [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) to implement your own FPS counter while using only integers, like this:

```
private int FrameCounter = 0;
private int Fps = 0;

void Start() 
{
    InvokeRepeating("CountFps", 0f, 1f);
}

void Update()
{
    FrameCounter++;
}

private void CountFps()
{
    Fps = FrameCounter;
    FrameCounter = 0;
}
```

Then just display the `Fps` variable in the `OnGUI()` method. Using this method, your `Fps` value will get updated every second; if you want more frequent updates, change the last argument of `InvokeRepeating` call and then adjust the `Fps` calculation accordingly.

Note, however, that `InvokeRepeating` takes `Time.timeScale` into account, so e.g. if you pause the game with `Time.timeScale = 0f;` the counter will stop updating until you unpause the game.

**FixedUpdate method**

Another approach is to count the FPS in `FixedUpdate()` method instead of `OnGUI()` or `Update()`. This gets called every `Time.fixedDeltaTime` seconds which is always the same, no matter what. The value of `Time.fixedDeltaTime` can be set globally for the project via menu `Edit->Project Settings->Time`, item `Fixed Timestep`.

In this case, you would count frames the same way (in `Update`), but update your FPS counter in `FixedUpdate` - which is basically the same as calling you own method with `InvokeRepeating("CountFps", 0f, 0.02f)` (`0.02f` being a typical `Time.fixedDeltaTime` value, but this depends on your project settings as per above).

**Conclusion**

Most of the time, you won't need to update the displayed FPS that often, so I personally like to use the `InvokeRepeating` method and 1 second intervals.

Answer (score 0):

OnGUI function is called at las twice per frame (sometimes more). You are calculating your "FPS" inside OnGUI so it will almost never be accurate.

Defining :

```
deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.05f;
```

will bring your FPS values closest to real but it will not be accurate if you calc it on OnGUI method.

I guess (not sure) that you should use `FixedUpdate()` instead of `OnGUI()` to calc your FPS. (also you don't need to change your deltaTime to multiply by 0.05f if you use FixedUpdate)